# Git Pull - Authentication Failure - BitBucket

Tags: git, authentication, bitbucket, git-pull

I recently had to reinstall windows. So, I also had to reinstall the command line Git client. I have tried versions 2.12.1 (x86 and 64x) Windows. I've also tried the same version for Mac OS. Since the Windows reinstall, I have not been able to do a Git pull from origin. At first, I thought I was just going crazy and had forgotten something about my credentials, but I've since confirmed over and over that my credentials are correct. The error I am getting is this:

*git.exe pull --progress -v --no-rebase "origin"
remote: Invalid username or password. If you log in via a third party service you must ensure you have an account password set in your account profile.
fatal: Authentication failed for '[INSERT REPO HERE]'
git did not exit cleanly (exit code 1) (11406 ms @ 24/03/2017 9:59:53 AM)*

At first, I thought it was a problem with my BitBucket account because I was able to log in to my BitBucket account with the same password. But then, I downloaded and installed GitKraken. GitKraken works differently because it does not use the command line version of Git. GitKraken ask me for my credentials, I entered them, and it was able to pull fine. Also, I'm able to pull in Visual Studio. It's almost as though there is a bug in this particular version of the Git command line tools.

So, there is some problem going on with the Git command line interface. As mentioned, I've tried both the 64bit and 32bit bit versions. I tried this line drop credentials cache:

git config --global --unset credential.helper

But, it made no difference.

Edit: I have since uninstalled and reinstalled the Git client. This time around, I unchecked the option to install the credentials manager in the installer. Now, instead of asking for my username and password, it just asks for my password, and I am able to pull. But, it asks for my password every single time. So, it appears that there is a bug in the credentials manager for the latest version of the Git client. **How can I fix the credentials manager in the Git Client?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I uninstalled Git, and when I reinstalled, I chose not to install the credentials manager. Then, I uninstalled and reinstalled with the credentials manager. After that it seemed to work. I also think that the problem was tied to a problem with BitBucket because several BitBucket users were experiencing the same problem and BitBucket even sent an email around about how they'd fixed the problem